# Is it allowed to not write a space after a period?

Tags: punctuation, writing, periods

I have come across quite a few cases where there are no space after a period:

> This is a sentence that ends here.A new sentence starts here.Note the lack of a space after the period.

A few contextual observations:

- This is done consequently in the entire text.
- All the posts in question are apparently written by non-native users. (A bit hard to determine, as I am not a native speaker myself.)
- From the user profiles of the authors, a majority of them are Indian. This may be purely coincidental due to a small sampling size. (approximately 8-10 cases)

What is the reason?

Comment: **Bad punctuation** or maybe they mistakenly think because "."(period) is a separator it works the same way as a " "(space).  In many word processing programs using a double-space automatically inserts a "." after the previous word, but you're right, to get this to happen it needs to be **intentional** these days

Comment: @Rathony I just thought I had missed something, like that this was an acceptable way of writing it. A "no" is enough.

Comment: Punctuation rules are very tricky. But there are firm and basic rules that are taught (or rather recommended). We need a space after a period to make it more clear and readable.

Comment: I have wondered the same thing myself.  I've seen plenty of Americans doing it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common thing people do, and not only in English. I think it comes from the time when young people were sending many SMS. And because one SMS can contain only 140 characters, people would omit spaces after punctuation signs. That's also the cause of popularity of acronyms and shortenings (U, aka, thx, afaik, etc.)

The time of message limitation is mostly gone, as people tend to use internet-messengers (skype, ICQ, Telegram, WhatsUp, etc.) instead of SMS, but some people are used to omitting spaces. Or think that omitting some characters would make them type faster. Or think that they are too lazy to type several spaces.

Comment: Twitter and comments on SE sites still have character limitations -  I'd rather have the space omitted than the period :) I think that you're right about people getting used to leaving the space out. I also think other people see space being left out and think that is the way it should be done these days without understanding why. It reminds me of the ["cut the ends off the roast"](http://www.snopes.com/weddings/newlywed/secret.asp) parable.

Comment: @ColleenV yes, there are places with character limitations, but it's a bit different now: you can post two tweets/comments/etc, it won't cost you anything. But with SMS you pay for each message, so saving characters is really important.